# About Akaike's criterion and VC-dimension of linear regressors

Tags: regression, vc-dimension

Akaike's model selection criterion is usually justified on the base that the empirical risk
of a ML estimator is a biased estimator of the true risk of the best estimator
in the parametric family, say the family of linear regressors on a m-dimensional variable, 
$S_m $

On the other hand, this family, $ S_m$, is known to have finite VC dimension ($VC = m+1$).
Having finite VC-dimension should grant that the empirical risk minimizer is
asymtotically consistent (Vapnik, "An overview of statistical learning theory")

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Although indeed the empirical risk of a ML estimator is biased, this does not contradict the asymptotic consistency because the bias depends on the sample size. Therefore, the empirical risk is **asymptotically unbiased**. However, since in practice we deal with finite sample sets, this does not mean we can always ignore the bias.

Answer (score 0):

Burham and Anderson's maximized log-likelihood IS Vapnik's empirical risk estimate of the optimal linear regressor; their EyEx[log(g(x| ˆ θ(y)))] is Vapnik's generalization error.

While Burham and Anderson claim to have proven that the maximized log-likelihood (the empirical risk) is a biased estimate of the generalization error, such claim contrdicts
a result by Vapnik that says that for classes with finite VC dimension the empirical risk is a consistent estimator of the generalization error. This is what I'm asking about!